# Windows function map?

Tags: windows, api, dependencies

Is there some sort of thing like a layout/plan of the windows api? A clear overview of which api depends on another? Or a website where they are linked in a hierarchical way (starting with the most dependable, ending with the core function)

e.g Kerenel32.dll!CreateFile() -> ntdll.dll!ntCreateFIle() -> ntoskrnl32.exe!zwCreateFile()

I can link them all by hand with a dependency walker but it takes much time. So I was just wondering if something like this already existed.

Comment: This is something that you really _should not know_. The reason why Windows, despite anything you can reproach to it, works so amazingly well across many different versions, is that you call `CreateFile` and don't know this kind of thing. It just works.

Comment: I will find out one way or another, so if you know where I can find such a layout would you please tell me?

Comment: There can be no such page, at least none that is correct. Look for example at the bottom of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will see that the _same function_ is found in _different DLLs_ in different versions of Windows, and the wrappers hide that. Which is my entire point: The programmer should not know, because knowing these details is a disadvantage, not an advantage (since the knowlege is _wrong_ 50% of the time).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to your question, but I think an even more interesting road would be to read what [Geoff Chappell](http://www.geoffchappell.com/) has found out regarding the [Windows Kernel](http://www.geoffchappell.com/windows/km/index.htm) and the [Win32 API](http://www.geoffchappell.com/windows/win32/index.htm). I have not read those sections, but so far everything I've read on that website has filled me with wonder and awe at how thoroughly things can be analysed given a disciplined and talented investigator.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it's not what I was looking for but I will certainly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a look at [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org):

> ReactOS® is a free, modern operating system based on the design of Windows® XP/2003. Written completely from scratch, it aims to follow the Windows-NT® architecture designed by Microsoft from the hardware level right through to the application level.

Simply search for whatever function in the [documentation](http://doxygen.reactos.org/) and look at its source. 99% of the time you can just pretend to be looking at the actual Windows source :) Very helpful when playing around with a debugger too.